# How to deselect files when using git interactive staging?

Tags: git

I know we can use something like `1,2,3` to select first 3 files. Is there a quick way to deselect them?

Comment: Inside the interactive staging, no, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the interactive staging command prompt after selecting files to be staged (each selected file is preceded by an asterisk `*`:

```
           staged     unstaged path
* 1:    unchanged        +4/-0 Gemfile
* 2:    unchanged        +2/-0 README.md
* 3:    unchanged        +1/-1 config.ru
Update>>
```

To undo your selection, simply prefix each entry number with a minus sign `-`, like so:

```
           staged     unstaged path
* 1:    unchanged        +4/-0 Gemfile
* 2:    unchanged        +2/-0 README.md
* 3:    unchanged        +1/-1 config.ru
Update>> -1,-3
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged        +4/-0 Gemfile
* 2:    unchanged        +2/-0 README.md
  3:    unchanged        +1/-1 config.ru
Update>>
```

Prefixing an entire range will undo everything in that range, e.g. `-1-3` undoes the selection of the range `1-3`.

You can find this information in the [official Linus kernel Git documentation for `git add` interactive mode](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html#_interactive_mode):

> To remove selection, prefix the input with "-" like this:
>
> ```
> Update>> -2
> ```

### Additional Resources on Interactive Staging

1. The [Pro Git book chapter on interactively staging and unstaging files](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-2.html#Staging-and-Unstaging-Files).

Comment: I don't want to exit the `update` mode then enter `revert` mode to achieve it. Is there any simple method?